# How to manage SQL DB from Jetty Server with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, sql, jetty

I am not realy a javascript developer but i have to try it.

I have a Jetty Server with sql DB.

Until now I used to manage the DB with Java software. Now I have to do it over Javascript and I have no idea how can I do it. I mean to create objects and to import them into the DB. The server is running and it should generate also some xml files as response or somethig like that. I think at all the result should be a webapp.

I only need some key words. Now I dont know where should I start and what should I search.

Answer (score 0):

You can't access the database directly from javascript. You need a servlet or a jsp page running in jetty to act as a proxy between the database and javascript.

Comment: Hi,Thanks for the answer. This could be a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You need *some* form of app between the web browser client and the DB. It could be through a thin RESTful layer, for example, using [Jersey](http://jersey.java.net/), [Restlets](http://www.restlet.org/), or simple servlets.

You may be able to leverage your existing Java code already if you can wrap it up as a service. With some care, you could use [DWR](http://directwebremoting.org/dwr/index.html) as a layer to make your Java code look like JavaScript on the client.

You may want to provide some additional details; it's not very clear what you need to actually do.

Comment: Hi,Thanks for the answer. It seems that I realy need something between javascript and server DB. I thought that it would be easier like when I use php to manage some sql db. I have a really big *.war file in the server folder. Could be possible that this is what I need? Otherwise there are a lot of jar and class files.So is this *.war file the key to the success?

Comment: @user1162738 A Java web app is the same as a PHP web app, but in Java. I have no idea what's in your WAR file--no clue if it's what you need or not. Can't see your machine from here.